# StaticHandler Error being triggered

Tags: tornado

I have a static handler as such:

```
  # Settings dict for Application
  settings = {
     "static_path": "static",
     "static_handler_class": BaseHandlerStatic,
  }
```

I override the write_error() in BaseHandlerStatic to handle error pages.

In my html I do something like this:

```
<object data="testingImageNotFound" type="image/jpeg">
   <img src="/static/Img/default.png"/>
</object>
```

I have tested that the default.png is there in the browser and when I type the whole address I.e. localhost:8000/static/Img/default.png the image shows.

However when I render the html within my template it continuously triggers a 404 Error from my BastHanderStatic. Does anyone know why this would be the case?

Comment: Ok it seems that the <object data=""> is triggering the error because it's not found and hence loading the Error page. How can I do this so that if there's an Error in the staticHandler I.e. not found i get the fallback instead?

Comment: triggering a 304 GET not sure what that means..